# Woocommerce variable product's total amount by javascript

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I have a plugin that update the product price depended on selected variation. My problem is that there are two prices that my plugin change just one of them. I want to change the code to update the total amount too. I want to know how can I change this amount by javascript.

[image: Wrong total amount]

I checked the page's template in `single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php` and find this line that generate the secound/total price:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
```

Is there any way to update this price that can show total amount by javascript?

Comment: There is.  You can do the math by grabbing values from different elements.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.